# A series of equations

Tags: analytic-geometry

ax+y-2=0
x-ay+3=0
2x+y-a=0

Find a if (a,a) lies inside the triangle formed by these three lines

Comment: This is not true, take $a=i$ and $b=0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe There are no inequalities with complex numbers.

Comment: Polymath, you should be careful when using AM-GM as it's only true for positive reals. And in this case, it's clear that a and b can be negative.

Comment: @Oussema Until you define it. For example, you can define for complex numbers  $a \geq b$ iff $a-b$ is a positive real number : it is natural and has sense.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's a useless definition. It is clear in the context of an inequality that the variables are reals.

Comment: @Oussema **Hint :** my comment was (maybe) a way to make the OP understand that his/her question needs some clarification.......

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I know. But there are better and more direct ways to go about that. There's nothing stopping you from telling them outright that their question needs further context. I find that the way you did it will only make the poster more confused instead of putting them on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, you have

$$ a^2+2ab+4b^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2+3b^2 =  (a+b)^2 +3b^2 \geq 0.$$